# tony millions reachability class - stopped working on ios device after upgrading xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi i am using tony millions reachability class.

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

i have been using this without issue until today.

in ANY IOS simulator for 6.1 and 7.0 this all works fine, but if i deploy to an actual IOS device the reachability blocks dont get fired. in the simulator all works fine, and i get ns log "connected" or not in the debug window and the code works fine.

with no modifications to the code, when ran on the device there are no debug messages and the code does not run. it doesnt generate an error either.

i have not actually changed any code since it was working on devices last week.

i have upgraded xcode to the latest version.

if it did not work on the simulators AND device, i would understand there is a problem with the code,but as it runs on the simulators, but not the device (tried on iPad running IOS 6.1 and iPhone running IOS 7.02 - both devices behave identically).

the code snipped it below.

any ideas?

```
// Checks if we have an internet connection or not
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    NSLog(@"before");
    self.reachable= [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
    NSLog(@"after");
    // Internet is reachable
    self.reachable.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NSLog(@"connected");
        //on simulator we get here and connected logged in debug window, but NOT on   

         //devices
        // Update the UI on the main thread

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self reachabilityChanged:YES];
        });
        [self.reachable stopNotifier];

    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    self.reachable.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NSLog(@"no connectiont");

        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self reachabilityChanged:NO];
        });
        [self.reachable stopNotifier];

    };

    [self.reachable startNotifier];
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error at all, that's half the problem. in the simulator the NSLog ("@connected") or NSLog(@"no connectiont"); are triggered depending on wether the internet is reachable, but on ANY device these sections of code are not called.